# Time series forecasting with Markov Chain, Markov Switch etc

Tags: forecasting, markov-chain-montecarlo, markov-process, hidden-markov-model

I have a data set which contains closing prices of a stock every day (total 1 year). Can i forecast that set like 1 or 2 year with using Markov methods? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is yes and No both. Markov methods can be used for forecasting.

You can refer this [link](http://multithreaded.stitchfix.com/blog/2016/04/21/forget-arima/)   for good explaination on Bayesian and MCMC sampling used in time series forecasting.

But please note time series forecasting majorly depends on the frequency of your data, And whatever data frequency you may consider you should atleast 2-3 cycles of data points to get some descent accuracy on forecasts.

Comment: please provide a full reference for your link so that users can access the resource in the future even if the link changes/dies

Comment: Please find it here https://multithreaded.stitchfix.com/blog/2016/04/21/forget-arima/